# Which type of files can be compressed with Huffman coding?

Tags: compression, huffman-code, image-compression

I know that we use Huffman Coding to compress **.txt** files what i want to know that which other extensions can be compressed using Huffman Coding for example can we compress (**.pdf, .Xls, .Jpg, .Gif, .Mp4**) files using Huffman Coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, you can compress *any* type of file with Huffman coding. Huffman coding works on the assumption that the input is a stream of symbols of some sort, and all files are represented as individual bytes, so any file is a valid input to a Huffman coder.

In practice, though, Huffman coding likely wouldn't work well for many other formats for a number of reasons. For example, many file formats (PDF, MP4, JPG, etc.) already employ some compression method to reduce their space usage, so hitting them with a secondary compressor isn't likely to do anything. Second, Huffman coding is based on the assumption that each symbol seen is sampled from some fixed probability distribution independently of any other symbol, and therefore doesn't do well when there are correlations between which symbols appear where. For example, a raw bitmap image is likely to have correlations between pixel colors and their neighboring pixels, but Huffman encoding can't take advantage of this.

That being said, Huffman coding is often used as one of many steps in various encoding algorithms. For example, if memory serves me correctly, bzip2 works by breaking the input into blocks, using the Burrows-Wheeler transform on each block, then using move-to-front coding, then run-length encoding, and then finally using Huffman encoding at the very end.

Hope this helps!